# How to square hallway and great room and vinyl plank install direction for a similar looking floor plan?

Tags: installation, vinyl-flooring, layout

First time DIYer here. Have a couple questions regarding the LVP flooring I purchased from Costco (Mohawk LVP Flooring).

- What should be the plank layout, run parallel to the hallway and follow the same direction in the great room or run horizontal/perpendicular to the hallway and extend the same direction to kitchen and great room?
- How to square between hallway and great room and kitchen so that the floor doesn't look crooked in these large rooms?

[image: Sample floor plan attached]

Comment: ATM machine. PIN number. LCD display. LVP plank. See where I'm going there?

Answer (score 2):

1. **Make it look best to *you* where you see it most.** Don't be concerned that a hallway may run crosswise. I recently did a floor where that was the case because the adjacent main room demanded it, and it looks perfectly fine (in fact, it's my preference over long, narrow runs). It also would in a hallway with a turn in it, where flooring is oriented in *both* directions at various points. Focus on the most visible areas.
2. **Examine the entire situation and compromise.** No house is perfectly square and no wall is perfectly straight. Set up some lines, square off them with the [3-4-5 technique](https://www.aconcordcarpenter.com/the-3-4-5-method-for-squaring-corners.html), and see what's what. Shift as needed to minimize visual wedges and small strips. There's always some oddness to deal with, so deal with it. Just try to know what you'll encounter before you get there so you can plan for it.

Comment: This is good advice. What I do is look for the one place where you absolutely need it to be square, e.g. a focal point in the layout, a long run across the living room seen from the entryway, whatever. Mark with a chalk line. Lay the floor around this reference point.